# How to determine the chunk limit based on the contents of the file I want to read in chunks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to work with a huge csv file, but I get OOM errors when trying to read it into a dataframe in one go. The solution would be to read it in chunks, but the issue is that I want to calculate things like the row count per identifier, and it is possible (likely, in fact), that my chunks would only contain part of the rows of one identifier.

Can anyone think of a way to solve this? One thing I tried was to only read one column (the identifier column) into a dataframe, and see at which indices the identifier changed, so that I could use this information to set my chunk sizes. However, even this single-column series is too big for my ram (16gb) so that does not work either.

Comment: This sounds like using the wrong tool for the job: import your CSV data into a database and query that instead? It's what databases were invented for =)

Comment: Yeah, if you'd end up reading the whole DF anyway, chunk sizes don't help you. If all you're doing is "row count per identifier", then don't use Pandas at all, but just read the l CSV line by line and use e.g. a `Counter()`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Agreed, I had not thought about it yet, but I will use sqlite!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I am using sqlite like you recommended and it works well. I have a follow-up question if you have the time: in sqlite I now have a table consisting of ~200 million rows and 6 columns, for which I only want to keep rows that are unique across all columns.
I am currently doing a CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM plates;
This has run for 10 hours and is still running so I must be doing something wrong. Any ideas on how to make this faster?

Comment: You would have to post that as a new question if after searching both SO and the web for how to do that doesn't find you that information.